# Downloading dependency using a custom repository

Tags: maven

My company just created a custom repository.  I am trying to download a dependency I added to the repository, but the jar doesn't seem to get added to my .m2 directory.

Maven isn't throwing any errors during the install.

Here is the repository in the POM file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://[domain]/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and the dependency:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.adobe.aem.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysqlAEM</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-20170313.175547-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Have also replaced the timestamp with SNAPSHOT.

The path within the repository is:

http://[domain]/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/adobe/aem/sql/mysqlAEM/

And i know the setup of where the JAR file is a little wonky, but I will fix that once I can get it downloaded to my local maven repository.

Comment: `mySQLAEM-SNAPSHOT` is also your version number ? can you confirm ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it lists in the POM file for the directory within artifactory

Comment: that's no good, maven can't recognize and bring artifact based on this version. Try changing version to supported one, refer http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html

Comment: I think you're confusing maven, yourself, and everyone here by using the same value for group id, artifact id, and version. I would start by varying these three and try to follow semantic versioning scheme (semver.org).

Comment: Even after changing them to be more appropriate, maven does not pull them in. Edit above

Comment: Can you try 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT for the dependency version in the pom? Maven will resolve the timestamp automatically. Also, is the dependency tag under dependencyManagement->dependencies by any chance?

Comment: Hey! That was the issue. Thank you!